# How do I put a image as the background for canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

So I stumbled upon this code the other day and I have been messing around with the code and trying to understand it. I was wondering how I could put a .png or .jpg image as the background of the canvas rather than the drawn image in the script.

Heres the link to where I found the code: http://docdingle.com/projects/games/Examples/waterRipple.html

What I've tried so far is replacing this portion of code

```
with (ctx)
{
    fillStyle = '#008888';
    fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    fillStyle = '#00ff77';
            
    // Save the transform state
    save();
            
    // Perform rotation to make diagonal lines
    rotate(-0.250);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        // Go long on the width to make certain we draw
        // across the entire viewable area --- with the rotation
        // Yes. This can be done more exactly, but this should make
        // it easier to play with the rotation value.
        fillRect(-width, i * step, width * 3, stripeWidth);
    }
            
     // Restore the transform state
     restore();
}
```

with

```
var background = new Image();
background.src = "https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/images6/Green-Aesthetic-Wallpaper-HD-Beautiful-1068x601.jpg";

background.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);   
}
```

This doesn't work. I'd appreciate it someone showed me and explained how to modify it so any image works. Thank you.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: you didn't tell how you got the `ctx` object and how you have your canvas element in your dom. Anyway I added that part and the code correctly rendered the picture as expected. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D

Comment: @DiegoD I attached a link to the whole code I found, since I didnt want to paste the whole code here. But in the code it has the  ctx object.

Comment: @Konrad theres no errors in the console. The image just doesn't display and the ripples dont work either.

Answer (score 3):

After awaiting for image to load and setting `crossOrigin` to `'Anonymous'` it works fine

```js
// code from http://docdingle.com/projects/games/Examples/waterRipple.html
(async() => {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('waterCanvas0');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var width = canvas.width;
  var height = canvas.height;
  var halfWidth = width >> 1;
  var halfHeight = height >> 1;
  var size = width * (height + 2) * 2; // space for 2 images (old and new), +2 to cover ripple radius <= 3
  var delay = 30; // delay is desired FPS
  var oldIdx = width;
  var newIdx = width * (height + 3); // +2 from above size calc +1 more to get to 2nd image
  var rippleRad = 3;

  var rippleMap = [];
  var lastMap = [];
  var mapIdx;

  // texture and ripple will hold the image data to be displayed
  var ripple;
  var texture;

  // Any image can be used, but we will create a simple pattern instead
  // So need some variables to create the background/underwater image
  var stripeWidth = 25;
  var step = stripeWidth * 2;
  var count = height / stripeWidth;

  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;

  // Here is a neat trick so you don't have to type ctx.blah over and over again
  with(ctx) {
    await new Promise(r => {
      var background = new Image();
      background.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'
      background.src = "https://i.imgur.com/Z3Dbkj9.jpg";

      background.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
        r()
      }
    })
  }

  // Initialize the texture and ripple image data
  // Texture will never be changed
  // Ripple is what will be altered and displayed --> see run() function
  texture = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
  ripple = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

  // Initialize the maps
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    lastMap[i] = 0;
    rippleMap[i] = 0;
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------------
  // --------------------- Main Run Loop --------------
  // -------------------------------------------------------
  function run() {
    newframe();
    ctx.putImageData(ripple, 0, 0);
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------------
  // Drop something in the water at location: dx, dy
  // -------------------------------------------------------
  function dropAt(dx, dy) {
    // Make certain dx and dy are integers
    // Shifting left 0 is slightly faster than parseInt and math.* (or used to be)
    dx <<= 0;
    dy <<= 0;

    // Our ripple effect area is actually a square, not a circle
    for (var j = dy - rippleRad; j < dy + rippleRad; j++) {
      for (var k = dx - rippleRad; k < dx + rippleRad; k++) {
        rippleMap[oldIdx + (j * width) + k] += 512;
      }
    }
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------------
  // Create the next frame of the ripple effect
  // -------------------------------------------------------
  function newframe() {
    var i;
    var a, b;
    var data, oldData;
    var curPixel, newPixel;

    // Store indexes - old and new may be misleading/confusing
    //               - current and next is slightly more accurate
    //               - previous and current may also help in thinking
    i = oldIdx;
    oldIdx = newIdx;
    newIdx = i;

    // Initialize the looping values - each will be incremented
    i = 0;
    mapIdx = oldIdx;

    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        // Use rippleMap to set data value, mapIdx = oldIdx
        // Use averaged values of pixels: above, below, left and right of current
        data = (
          rippleMap[mapIdx - width] +
          rippleMap[mapIdx + width] +
          rippleMap[mapIdx - 1] +
          rippleMap[mapIdx + 1]) >> 1; // right shift 1 is same as divide by 2

        // Subtract 'previous' value (we are about to overwrite rippleMap[newIdx+i])
        data -= rippleMap[newIdx + i];

        // Reduce value more -- for damping
        // data = data - (data / 32)
        data -= data >> 5;

        // Set new value
        rippleMap[newIdx + i] = data;

        // If data = 0 then water is flat/still,
        // If data > 0 then water has a wave
        data = 1024 - data;

        oldData = lastMap[i];
        lastMap[i] = data;

        if (oldData != data) // if no change no need to alter image
        {
          // Recall using "<< 0" forces integer value
          // Calculate pixel offsets
          a = (((x - halfWidth) * data / 1024) << 0) + halfWidth;
          b = (((y - halfHeight) * data / 1024) << 0) + halfHeight;

          // Don't go outside the image (i.e. boundary check)
          if (a >= width) a = width - 1;
          if (a < 0) a = 0;
          if (b >= height) b = height - 1;
          if (b < 0) b = 0;

          // Set indexes
          newPixel = (a + (b * width)) * 4;
          curPixel = i * 4;

          // Apply values
          ripple.data[curPixel] = texture.data[newPixel];
          ripple.data[curPixel + 1] = texture.data[newPixel + 1];
          ripple.data[curPixel + 2] = texture.data[newPixel + 2];
        }
        mapIdx++;
        i++;
      }
    }
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------------
  // Select random location to create drops
  // So if user is doing nothing, water still
  // gets ripples.
  // -------------------------------------------------------
  function randomDrop() {
    // Make it a little, irregular in timing
    if (Math.random() > 0.3) {
      dropAt(Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height);
    }
  }
  // -------------------------------------------------------
  // Adjust mouse position to account for canvas placement
  // -------------------------------------------------------
  function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      // add Math.round( ) around the below to get rid of excessive decimals
      x: Math.round((evt.clientX - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left) * canvas.width),
      y: Math.round((evt.clientY - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top) * canvas.height)
    };
  }
  // -------------------------------------------------------
  // Event handler for mouse motion
  // -------------------------------------------------------
  canvas.onmousemove = function( /* Event */ evt) {
    //dropAt(evt.offsetX || evt.layerX, evt.offsetY || evt.layerY);
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    var mx = mousePos.x;
    var my = mousePos.y;
    dropAt(mx, my);
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------------
  // Begin our infinite loop
  // For user interaction and display updates
  // -------------------------------------------------------
  setInterval(run, delay);

  // -------------------------------------------------------
  // Create random ripples
  // Note: this is NOT at same rate as display refresh
  // -------------------------------------------------------
  setInterval(randomDrop, 1250);
})()
```

```css
.waterCanvasStyle {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #a1a1d0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: #c6c6d0 4px 4px 10px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="waterCanvas0" width="400" height="400">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have a question about the code:

`
with(ctx) {
    await new Promise(r => {
      var background = new Image();
      background.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'
      background.src = "https://i.imgur.com/Z3Dbkj9.jpg";

      background.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
        r()
      }
    })
  }
`
what does the r() mean?

Comment: [It](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-]US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#parameters) resolves the promise